# Is it needed to specify a systemd unit both on "Wants=" and "After=" lines or is "After=" enough?

Tags: systemd

Let's say, that I have a systemd service type of unit which contains both following `Wants=` and `After=` statements:

```
Wants=foo.service
After=foo.service
```

Do I really need to specify the `foo.service` on `Wants=` if it is already on `After=`? Or maybe the `Wants=foo.service` is needed because if no units specify the `foo.service` as `Wants=` or `Requires=`, then the `foo.service` is not started at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, both are possible, both of them do something, but they have a distinct effect, so you'll want to keep the `Wants=` in cases where you want to make sure the `foo.service` unit is started whenever your other unit is started.

If you only have an ordering dependency, such as `After=foo.service`, then that only means that if both units are being started (in the same transaction), then systemd will start `foo.service` first (and wait until it is completely started) before starting the current unit.

That is useful when you don't necessarily know whether `foo.service` is enabled or not, your service works either way, but **if** `foo.service` is enabled, you would like to have it start before your service.

> Or maybe the `Wants=foo.service` is needed because if no units specify the `foo.service` as `Wants=` or `Requires=`, then the `foo.service` is not started at all?

Yes, that is correct. The `After=` and `Before=` directives are ordering-only directives, so they don't pull the other unit, only affect the ordering if the unit is already being started through other means (usually it being directly enabled itself, or possibly through a `Wants=` or `Requires=` dependency on a third unit.)